# Draining a job with processing_time timer

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working with a dataflow job with stateful processing and timer. The processus is simplified as below :

1. Receiving messages from PubSub Subscription.
2. Keeping documents into bagState.
3. Checking with a loop timer (processing_time) if all conditions are met

   - if ok, clear bagState and generate a new message to next step.
4. Convert and send message to PubSub Topic.

Don't have set particular windowing policies, so I'm using GlobalWindow (as I understood).

When draining is performed (with continuously incoming message - 1k/sec - don't know if it could be related), the job raise this exception :

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to set a processing-time timer with an output timestamp of 294247-01-10T04:00:54.775Z that is after the expiration of window 294247-01-09T04:00:54.775Z
```

with related stacktrace :

```
org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:440)
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$TimerInternalsTimer.setAndVerifyOutputTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:1229)
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$TimerInternalsTimer.setRelative(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:1138)
xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.transform.AggregateLogsAuditFn.onLoopIteration(AggregateLogsAuditFn.java:292)
```

This error handles when resetting loop timer in @ProcessElements method (or whatever in @OnTimer) :

```
loopTimer.offset(Duration.standardSeconds(loopTimerSec.get())).setRelative();
```

The timer (and it's value) are declared as :

```
@TimerId("loopTimer") private final TimerSpec loopTimer = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);
private ValueProvider<Integer> latenessTimerSec;
```

As an exception is raised, the job won't stop properly ; and we need to cancel it.

Please note that updating the job (with --update) is working fine, and this exception never appears when the job is running normally.

Thanks for your advices, Lionel.

Answer (score 0):

Draining advances the watermark to "the end of time" (aka 294247-01-10) and the error seems to indicate that a timer is being set to shortly after this. To make th loop timer compatible with drain you should avoid setting it if the current time is this high.